# Indexing on sensitive data

Tags: elasticsearch

We need to be able to search a lot of personally identifiable information. We were thinking of using ElasticSearch for this but have a problem with the fact that it stores the original document.

Is there a way to index on a field, but not store the field? In this case, if we got a hit on a record, we would get back the guid - or more likely the encrypted guid - of a record in dynamoDB that would contain the original document. But if someone managed to pinch the ES database they couldn't easily reconstruct the original information.

Thanks,

Adam.

Comment: Have you considered hashing those sensitive fields? This is one-way operation, so should not be possible to reconstruct. But you still should be able to search for the necessary field, if you have the hashing key.

Comment: @Tofig. Thanks for the response. It's not that there are parts within the doc that can be redacted out; we have a block of text we'd like to pass through some filters (such as the stemming filter) so we can do a full text search on it, but don't want the doc itself to be stored after it's been indexed. Did I explain that OK?

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess hashing won't work then. However, since 5.3 version of ElasticSearch it has a support for disk level encryption using dm-crypt. Is that something that can help?

Comment: Maybe - our problem is if we suffer a data breach the fines are quite harsh - we're basically finished. I believe the ideal is that if someone could hack the database and get a dump of it we wouldn't have to worry. Disk level encryption wouldn't help us there because if someone hacked in they would be able to get data in plaintext. If all we had was the index without the source doc that wouldn't be true. Sigh. It's a bit of a conundrum - customers want everything extremely searchable with maximum security.

Comment: @AdamBenson You can check out this article, it solves your problem: 
https://medium.com/@jaiswalbishal3/how-to-store-sensitive-data-in-elasticsearch-306f49373586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html

You can disable storing the original source document, only having the index - just what I wanted. We will be storing the original docs in Amazon's DyanmoDB - encrypted, of course. The ES indexes will allow us to perform the searches we want without storing the original doc.

The ES doc's do stress thinking carefully about this approach - for example, if we needed to re-index we'd have to pull everything out of Dynamo and feed it through ES again.

As a side note, we've recently been to the AWS Summit and they encouraged us to look at Kinesis as the pipeline for indexing the docs and then storing them in DynamoDB.

Adam

Comment: But the PII data will be still in plaintext in the index, so how does it solve your problem?

Comment: Good point, actually. At the time we were just concerned about making it harder work to get the data. In the end, after much discussion, we decided we had no option but to store everything in plaintext and protect the server itself. So I guess this question is out of date. I'll have a re-read of it later, see if anything can be done with it and if not I'll delete it. Thanks for your response :-)

Comment: SO strongly discourage deleting questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question. So I guess I'll leave it as it is. The point of how not to store the whole doc may be useful to someone.